# Creating one toolbar for different screens in Android app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on app, where I am using toolbar on many screens(activities) with different image buttons and main title. For this, I need to create .xml for every screen to create a toolbar and include that in .xml file of corresponding screen. I want that I use only one .xml file for the toolbar instead of creating each toolbar for each screens and edit it (I mean change title or add buttons) either programatically or in one .xml for for relevant screen. Is there any way? Below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Main Activity toolbar-->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/barColor"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="MAIN ACTIVITY"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:onClick="GoBack"
        android:background="@null"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Main Screen design .xml file, where I include this toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3A3A3B"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--Including the toolbar in main screen here-->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainbar"
        layout="@layout/mainactivitytoolbar"
        />
    <TextureView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scanView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here if I need to add this toolbar in another screen with one more ImageButton, I need to design another toolbar .xml file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/barColor"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="SECOND ACTIVITY"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:onClick="Back"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <!--New Image button added-->
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/serial"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="Enter"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: For toolbar title you can change it programmatically and for icon create all icons in one toolbar and toggle their visibility on/off depending on your requirement

Comment: But I need icon at same place(Right Corner) on toolbar, Is it still possible?

Comment: yes but in that case you have to do it using `Relative layout` instead of `Toolbar`

Comment: Do you mean to create my own widget instead of using default toolbar widget.

Comment: yes and that's not difficult at all . Everything will work same way except with navigation drawer. With drawer you have to use toolbar

Comment: I am using navigating to different screens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109533/discussion-between-wasimsafdar-and-vivek-mishra).

Comment: Toolbar will only be required for activity in which you have defined Navigation drawer. I rest of activities you can use it the way I suggested

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using below solution.

First create the toolbar.xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--Main Activity toolbar-->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#aa2"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="MAIN ACTIVITY"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftIconContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightIconContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then create a BaseActivity as below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 4/19/2016.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private View customToolBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void registerToolBar(){
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        customToolBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar,null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customToolBar,layout);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) actionBar.getCustomView().getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);

    }

    public void addToolBarRightIcon(View view){
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.rightIconContainer);
        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }

    public void addToolBarLeftIcon(View view){
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.leftIconContainer);
        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }

    public void changeTitle(String title){
        TextView textView = (TextView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        textView.setText(title);
    }

    public int getCorrectSize(float value) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        return (int) px;
    }
}
```

And then when you create a new Activity **you must extends BaseActivity** and also **you must call registerToolBar() method in onCreate() after setContentView()** method. **You can add icons to left by calling addToolBarLeftIcon(pass your image view here)** and the same way **add icons to right by calling addToolBarRightIcon(pass your image view here)**. See below for an example.

According to my example I am creating a sample activity called Main2Activity.

```
public class Main2Activity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        registerToolBar();
        addIcons();
        changeTitle("Activity 2");
    }


    private void addIcons(){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getCorrectSize(25), getCorrectSize(25));
        layoutParams.setMargins(getCorrectSize(8),0,0,0);
        ImageView rightImage = new ImageView(this);
        rightImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        rightImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        rightImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        addToolBarRightIcon(rightImage);

        layoutParams.setMargins(getCorrectSize(8),0,0,0);
        ImageView leftImage = new ImageView(this);
        leftImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        leftImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        leftImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        addToolBarLeftIcon(leftImage);
    }
}
```

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks, your solution is right but I found even more simpler solution. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer that I found simplest. A tool with all the icons or buttons you need and assign them relevant ID's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/barColor"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="SECOND ACTIVITY"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id = "@+id/leftBtn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:onClick="Back"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <!--New Image button added-->
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id = "@+id/rightBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/serial"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="Enter"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in your main activity, just hide what you do not need. You can also place as many icons as want in same place.:)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton rightBtn,crossBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nbe_startqr);

        //Hide right button on toolbar
        rightBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.righBtn);
        rightBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        crossBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.leftBtn);
        crossBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    public void Back(View view)
    {
       //Your code here
    }
    public void Enter(View view)
    {
       //Your code here
    }
```

Comment: So how do you add another image button to left side or right side of the tool bar using this solution?

Comment: Just add using same parameters, if you want to place another image at same place. Only change the id. In xml, you will see that image button shifted to right or left of image button for which you want to replace. But when you run the code, it will move to it's right place.

Comment: OK.. But in my solution you don't have to edit the xml file all the time and also you can add views dynamically to left side of right side easily. What you have to do is pass your ImageView to addToolBarRightIcon() method or addToolBarLeftIcon() method.

Comment: Yes, your solution is also right, but in this you do not need need to edit xml file all the time. Just create generic toolbar with everything and then hide or show what you need in the activity.